# White backgrounds on google map images/control elements

Tags: google-maps

Can someone let me know what are those ugly white backgrounds on controls/images in a google map i created? How i can remove them?

[gmap-controls-white-backgrounds-bug http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/4523/mapbugwhitebkgs.png](http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/4523/mapbugwhitebkgs.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad! Found that those white backgrounds were created by [K2](http://www.getk2.org) component for Joomla with this css rule:

```
.itemFullText img { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF; }
```